# How to make YOLOv3 only detect one object type?

Tags: python, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

Using YOLOv3 I want to count one specific object type (I'm trying to count cars only). It can detect more than 1 item (like car, person, can etc.), it can make `"if label != 'car' :"passed`.

How can I get only objects with 'car' in label (or is there any solution that rewrites `"if label != 'car' :"`)? My code:

```
While cap.isOpened():  
    cls = int(x[-1])
    label = "{0}".format(classes[cls])
    if label == 'car' :
        buffer = True
    if label != 'car' :
        if buffer == True :
            find = True
    if find == True :
        car = car + 1
        buffer = False
        find = False
```

Comment: You can skip on drawing rectangles around the objects you don't want to show up and use the rest for further processing. Make a list of classes that you want to skip. If detected class exist on that list skip it. Another way is to train on your own classes that you want detect.

Comment: I see.I will try to code make it skip